# bound on vertices of graph with path

Tags: graph-theory

**Question:**

> Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph with $n$ vertices that has vertices $u,v$ such that $dist(u,v)=3b$ for a positive integer $b$. Let $\delta$ be the minimum degree of $G$. Prove that $(b+1)(\delta +1 ) \le n$.

**Thoughts:**
I've tried to prove this by induction on $\delta$. For $0$ and $1$ it's obvious. The thing I'm having trouble with is seeing how I do the induction step. I know that in any case the graph is not allowed to add any "shortening" edges to the $3b$ path - this implies that each vertex in the path is a part of a sub-"component" that is only connected to the rest of the graph via the path-vertex (or: each sub-component can be connected to either previous or next sub-component, as long as it doesn't break the "rule" I defined here regarding min path length from $u$ to $v$).

If I have a graph of of min degree $\delta$ then I wish to somehow remove things from it in order for the induction to work. If I remove an edge and decrease the min degree I don't understand how can $n$ decrease. If I remove a node (perhaps not a path node) what does that neccesarily have to do with $\delta$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a special case of a theorem in [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0095-8956(89)90066-X).

The key idea is to set $S_i = \{w \in V \mid \operatorname{dist}(u,w) = i\}$ and observe that $$|S_{i-1}| + |S_i| + |S_{i+1}| \geq \delta + 1 \text{ for all } 0 \leq i \leq 3b$$
(please note the weak inequalities, in particular $S_{-1} = \varnothing$),
which gives you

$$n \geq \sum_{i=(-1)}^{3b+1}|S_i| = \sum_{j=0}^{b}|S_{3j-1}| + |S_{3j}| + |S_{3j+1}| \geq (b+1)(\delta+1).$$

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: nice solution . but is there a way to solve it by contradiction ? by assuming $n < (b+1)(\delta + 1)$ and getting a contradiction .

Comment: @BorisMorozov Sure, for example you can start with your assumption, and then arrive at my last line which is clearly a contradiction, but what for? Proofs by contradiction are, in a sense, _weaker_ than direct proofs.

Comment: this question is from an old exam. And there is not a chance i would've been able to solve it by myself if i got it on the exam, in this specific way . so i wondering is there way to solve it using only the standard theorems/tools from the first undergraduate course of graph theory

Comment: @BorisMorozov Perhaps there is some mundane solution, but I am not aware of it. On the other hand, although this is a rather hard problem, it is not impossible to find such a proof (perhaps not as streamlined, but working). Also, that could have been one of the remember-from-class questions, who knows?